# How to give access to one specific bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon AWS account and I'm using Amazon S3.

I'd like to give access to specific people to a Amazon S3 bucket.

Here's what I'd like to do :

- Amazon AWS: Access limited to my account
- Amazon S3: Access limited to my account
- Bucket "website-photos": Access authorized to 3 people that will be able to read and write in the bucket through AWS management console.
- Files in the bucket "website-photos": Public can read them.

How can I setup this config?

Answer (score 1):

Just create an IAM policy and attach to the users you want to give access:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

See: [Amazon S3: Allows Read and Write Access to Objects in an S3 Bucket - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_rw-bucket.html)

Comment: How can I attach this policy to the users?

Comment: It works perfectly, I also read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_rw-bucket-console.html

Comment: Nice, @Alizée! I am glad that worked for you! Now if you can mark my answer to help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is:

- If you want something to be "public" (accessible by anyone), then use a **Bucket Policy**
- If you want to only assign permissions to a specific IAM User, then **attach a policy to the IAM User**
- If you want to only assign permissions to a group of IAM Users, then create an **IAM Group**, attach a policy and assign the group to the desired IAM Users